# Update JsonNode with new object values

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I am getting JsonNode where one of the key's value is null. Need to update this value with object.

Value of m  return will be like as below where notes is null and need to update this notes value.

```
{
 "a":"aaaaaa",
 "b":"bbbbbb",
 "notes":null,
}
```

Code tried where m coming as JsonNode:

```
return seasonsAdapter.callSeasonsJsonAPI(seasonId, hunterId, uuid).map(m -> {
String notes=AppJsonUtil.getJsonAsString(seasonsNotesDto);
ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) m;
ObjectNode objectNode1=objectNode.put("notes", notes);
objectNode1.put("notesText", seasonsNotesDto.getNotesText());
objectNode1.put("notesTime", seasonsNotesDto.getNotesTime());
objectNode1.put("notesTitle", seasonsNotesDto.getNotesTitle());
return m;
});
```

Result :

```
  {
   "a":"aaaaaa",
   "b":"bbbbbb",
  "notes": "{\"notesText\":\"this is my new note 1 \",\"notesTitle\":\"new note 1 Title\",\"notesTime\":1640865242125}",

    "notesText": "this is my new note 1 ",

    "notesTime": 1640865242125,

    "notesTitle": "new note 1 Title"
   }
```

Expected :

```
  {
   "a":"aaaaaa",
   "b":"bbbbbb",
  "notes": {
           "notesText": "this is my new note 1 ",
            "notesTime": 1640865242125,
            "notesTitle": "new note 1 Title"
           }
   }
```

Comment: Ditch your `notes` `String`. Create an `ObjectNode` instead, add the fields to that, then add it to `objectNode1`. Alternatively, see if your `AppJsonUtil` has a mechanism that converts an object to an `ObjectNode` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out what needs to do. check below code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode obj = (ObjectNode) m;
    if (seasonsNotesDto!=null)
    {
        ObjectNode notes = mapper.createObjectNode();
        notes.put("notesTitle", seasonsNotesDto.getNotesTitle());   
        notes.put("notesText", seasonsNotesDto.getNotesText()); 
        notes.put("notesTime", seasonsNotesDto.getNotesTime()); 
        obj.set("notes", notes);
    }
    return m;
```